# findIndex is not a function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

First of all, I know this question has been asked multiple times before, but there's not any solution to my answer. I have searched and tried various different thing like making it an object, using filter, some, etc, but there's nothing that seems to work.

I have used this code before (about 6 months ago) and it worked then.

Code:

> ```
> editByIdSuccess: (state, draggedEvent) => {
>     let index = state.events.findIndex(event => event.id === draggedEvent.id);
>     if(index !== -1){
>         state.events.splice(index, 1, draggedEvent);
>     }
> },
> ```

Returns "Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: state.events.findIndex is not a function". I have also tried to create a function out of this and tried to use Object.Assign.

The state is an array, defined like this:

```
const state = {
    events: []
};
```

Answers with explanation is appreciated so I can understand why I can't do the code like this anymore.

Comment: @Andreas, thanks, I saw it after I posted. I changed it now.

Comment: Check the type of `state.events` before trying to use it. Maybe it's overridden somewhere.

Comment: @Teemu, I think you're right here. Seems like the state is changed somewhere, but I'm unable to figure out where. Thanks for the heads up!

Comment: @Teemu, you were completely right! Thanks a lot for a quick solution.

Answer (score 0):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some

As per the documentation on MDN, Array.prototype.some returns a boolean value.

You can change it to:

```
 let isEventPresent = state.events.some(event => event.id === draggedEvent.id);
    if(isEventPresent){
        state.events.splice(index, 1, draggedEvent);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, however, I have already read through the docs and using some still returns the same error as findIndex. It's probably somewhere the state is changed to an object instead of an array, but to be honest I have no idea.

Comment: You can use isArray to find out if the state is object or array. If it's object you can convert it to array  https://www.javascripttutorial.net/object/convert-an-object-to-an-array-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

As @Teemu said, the state changes to an object somewhere before.

> Check the type of state.events before trying to use it. Maybe it's
> overridden somewhere. – Teemu